# Mount script cannot be created. mount: No such file or directory

Tags: internal-storage, root-access, mount

I have micromax bolt a58, I have rooted it with farmaroot and install link2sd but it didnt work 
when i formatted it with ext2 it says try with fat32, and when i do so it gives error - Mount script cannot be created.
 mount: No such file or directory
Please help me...

Comment: You need to say exactly what steps you took and what commands you ran, and the order you did them. Say at what step you got each result, and the exact text of any error messages.

Comment: I was following this post
 http://www.aagneyam.com/blog/?p=80412

Everything was fine but problem is - Link2SD will ask to select the file system of your second partition i.e ext2 ,ext3 , ext4 or FAT32 

this is where I am facing the problem... If I am going with ext2, ext3, ext4 Erro: your device did not support extX, try with fat32. and when i go with FAT32 Error : Mount script cannot be created. mount: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Wat are you using to create and format your partitions? I ran into a similar error when I used Paragon Partition Manager (https://www.paragon-software.com/) in Windows. The phone wouldn't correctly recognise the partition.

I then used (I think it's the 'official') the SD Formatter program in windows to format my partition but it only seems to make use of the entire sd card and not really give you an opportunity to have multiple partitions.

You should really try GParted. It's pretty fool proof. Just make a bootable USB, pop on GParted and create and format you partitions in that. Good guide here for a GS4 but should work for your phone too: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2285221